# cv2.groupRectangles() returning empty tuple - Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to group rectangles together using `cv2.groupRectangles()` but it returns empty tuple `()`

I tried using 2 different versions of opencv-python (4.6.0.66 and 3.4.18.65)

‎This is the code:

```py
# "do" object detection
rectangles = np.array([
    [530, 119,  47,  47],
    [641, 117,  53,  53],
    [531,  89, 117, 117]])
print(rectangles)
print()

(rect, weights) = cv2.groupRectangles(rectangles, groupThreshold=1, eps=0.5)
print("rect after cv.groupRectangles:", rect)
```

And this is the output:

```
[[530 119  47  47]
 [641 117  53  53]
 [531  89 117 117]]

rect after cv.groupRectangles: ()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are your initial rectangles for reference. How were you wanting those to be merged?

[image: rectangles]

You might have chosen `groupThreshold` badly.

If that is more than 0, the function will remove any rectangles that aren't "confirmed" by nearby neighbors. With `0`, it's allowed to leave single rectangles alone...

```py
>>> cv.groupRectangles(rectangles, groupThreshold=0, eps=0)
(array([[530, 119,  47,  47],
       [641, 117,  53,  53],
       [531,  89, 117, 117]]), array([1, 1, 1]))
```

But then it also doesn't seem to want to merge any of them. That `eps` doesn't seem to behave all that "relatively". I get effects when I increase it beyond 1.0.

Documentation is very poor about this. Perhaps this function is broken. If not broken, then it's at least not documented well enough *for me* to make sense of it and I think I'm proficient with OpenCV.